# Change position of Text on Button when pressed

Tags: android, button, text

I have Button with Text and custom background. When I press on button background is slightly move down ("effect of pressing"). But Text stays at the same position.

**What should I do to move the text, when button is pressed?**

I've tried text selector, selector padding, but it didn't work for me.

Button:

```
<Button
     android:background="@drawable/button_blue"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textSize="30sp"
     android:textColor="@drawable/selector_txt"
     android:text="Push me"/>
```

Selector:

```
<selector>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_unpressed" />
</selector>
```

Button states:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#aac2bfbf" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="2dp"
    android:top="2dp">
    <shape >
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/darkFab"
            android:startColor="@color/actionBackColor" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>

<layer-list>
<item
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="3dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#aac2bfbf" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="2dp">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/darkFab"
            android:startColor="@color/actionBackColor" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/disabled" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Text selector:

```
<selector>
  <item  android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

Comment: can you share your xml file

Comment: did you find a solution? I am having the same problem..

Comment: more or less, look there: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497519/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5 . But there was a problem with layout after.

Answer (score 0):

You could programmatically change the padding of the button when you press it.

Assign the button an ID in your XML file:

```
android:id="@+id/button_id
```

Then, wherever you handle the button press:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
myButton.paddingTop(0, X, 0, 0); // X will be in pixles, I believe
```

The method is defined as:

public void setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)

in the View class in the Android SDK.

Comment: yes, I've tried it too. Problems: padding is applied AFTER click. TouchEvent is unsuitable. I think, that there is a way simplier. Thx for answer.